# Having trouble creating a trigger for syncing two databases

Tags: android, sql, database, triggers

I was wondering if someone could confirm that I am creating TRIGGER correctly. I am syncing the normal table to the FTS table for the purpose of being able to use search. But I can't just use FTS alone for some reason since I am obtaining an empty cursor for every search and it only works with normal databases.

```
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "CONTACT";
public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "CONTACTS";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE_FTS = "CONTACTS_FTS";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 20;
private Context ourContext;
private DbHelper DBHelper;
private static SQLiteDatabase db;
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = 
        "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
         COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
         COL_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
         COL_EMAIL + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
         COL_CELL + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
         COL_ARRIVAL + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
         COL_DEPARTURE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
         COL_FLIGHT_NUMBER + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
         COL_HOTEL_ROOM_NUMBER + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
         COL_EVENT1 + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
         COL_EVENT2 + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
         COL_EVENT1_ROOM + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
         COL_EVENT2_ROOM + " TEXT NOT NULL);";

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_FTS = 
        "CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE_FTS + " USING fts3(" +
        "content=" + "\"CONTACTS\", " + 
        COL_NAME + ");";

private static final String Trigger = 
        "CREATE TRIGGER contacts_Trigger " + 
        "AFTER INSERT "+ "ON " + DATABASE_TABLE +
        " BEGIN " +
        "INSERT " + DATABASE_TABLE_FTS + " SET " + COL_NAME + " = new.COL_NAME WHERE " + COL_ID + " = old.COL_ID;" +
        " END;";
```

Comment: yes, but I didn't specify much in that post. I wanted to repost because no one even looked at it but me.

Comment: The proper approach is to edit your existing question and provide additional information as necessary. That will bump the question. Adding a duplicate question is bad form and discouraged, because it dilutes the information available here.